# PHP and RegEx: Split a string by commas that are not inside brackets (and also nested brackets)

Tags: php, regex, parsing, split

Two days ago I started working on a code parser and I'm stuck.

How can I split a string by commas that are not inside brackets, let me show you what I mean:

I have this string to parse:

```
one, two, three, (four, (five, six), (ten)), seven
```

I would like to get this result:

```
array(
 "one"; 
 "two"; 
 "three"; 
 "(four, (five, six), (ten))"; 
 "seven"
)
```

but instead I get:

```
array(
  "one"; 
  "two"; 
  "three"; 
  "(four"; 
  "(five"; 
  "six)"; 
  "(ten))";
  "seven"
)
```

How can I do this in PHP RegEx.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that easier:

```
preg_match_all('/[^(,\s]+|\([^)]+\)/', $str, $matches)
```

But it would be better if you use a real parser. Maybe something like this:

```
$str = 'one, two, three, (four, (five, six), (ten)), seven';
$buffer = '';
$stack = array();
$depth = 0;
$len = strlen($str);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    $char = $str[$i];
    switch ($char) {
    case '(':
        $depth++;
        break;
    case ',':
        if (!$depth) {
            if ($buffer !== '') {
                $stack[] = $buffer;
                $buffer = '';
            }
            continue 2;
        }
        break;
    case ' ':
        if (!$depth) {
            continue 2;
        }
        break;
    case ')':
        if ($depth) {
            $depth--;
        } else {
            $stack[] = $buffer.$char;
            $buffer = '';
            continue 2;
        }
        break;
    }
    $buffer .= $char;
}
if ($buffer !== '') {
    $stack[] = $buffer;
}
var_dump($stack);
```

Comment: Yes, it's easier, but doesn't work in case of nested brackets, like so: one, two, three, (four, (five, six), (ten)), seven

Comment: That’s the point where you have to use a real parser. Regular expressions cannot count or handle states.

Comment: I have to use regular expressions. Regular expressions are recursive and greedy, you can accomplish this using them.

Comment: No you can’t. Sure, there are features in modern implementations that can accomplish that such like .NET’s *Balancing group* `(?<name1-name2> … )` http://msdn.microsoft.com/bs2twtah.aspx. But they use a state machine and that’s no longer a regular expression in the classical manner.

Comment: This one is more correct, but still not working for nested parenthesis /[^(,]*(?:\([^)]+\))?[^),]*/

Answer (score 6):

Hm... OK already marked as answered, but since you asked for an easy solution I will try nevertheless:

```
$test = "one, two, three, , , ,(four, five, six), seven, (eight, nine)";
$split = "/([(].*?[)])|(\w)+/";
preg_match_all($split, $test, $out);
print_r($out[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => (four, five, six)
    [4] => seven
    [5] => (eight, nine)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your help is much appreciated. But now I realize that I will also encounter nested brackets and your solution doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, directly.  You'd need, at minimum, variable-width lookbehind, and last I knew PHP's PCRE only has fixed-width lookbehind.

My first recommendation would be to first extract parenthesized expressions from the string.  I don't know anything about your actual problem, though, so I don't know if that will be feasible.

Comment: Yes, that was the hack I was planing to use. Replace the brackets with $1, $2 or something similar, split the string and than restore the brackets in the result. Thank you !

Comment: The point is that what you describe is not a regular language, so regular expressions are an ill fit.  So, parsing out all the nested parts first is not a "hack" but the most sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to do it using a single regex, but it's quite easy to hack together something that works:

```
function process($data)
{
        $entries = array();
        $filteredData = $data;
        if (preg_match_all("/\(([^)]*)\)/", $data, $matches)) {
                $entries = $matches[0];
                $filteredData = preg_replace("/\(([^)]*)\)/", "-placeholder-", $data);
        }

        $arr = array_map("trim", explode(",", $filteredData));

        if (!$entries) {
                return $arr;
        }

        $j = 0;
        foreach ($arr as $i => $entry) {
                if ($entry != "-placeholder-") {
                        continue;
                }

                $arr[$i] = $entries[$j];
                $j++;
        }

        return $arr;
}
```

If you invoke it like this:

```
$data = "one, two, three, (four, five, six), seven, (eight, nine)";
print_r(process($data));
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => (four, five, six)
    [4] => seven
    [5] => (eight, nine)
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this should work. This was how I planned to do it first, but I thought that an easier way exists.

Comment: You're method can not parse "one, two, three, ((five), (four(six))), seven, eight, nine". I think the correct RegEx would be a recursive one: /\(([^()]+|(?R))*\)/.

Comment: You didn't mention that it had to be able to parse recursive expressions back when I first wrote this answer, though. Still, others have definately suggested better solutions after I wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late but I've made a solution without regex which also supports nesting inside brackets. Anyone let me know what you guys think:

```
$str = "Some text, Some other text with ((95,3%) MSC)";
$arr = explode(",",$str);

$parts = [];
$currentPart = "";
$bracketsOpened = 0;
foreach ($arr as $part){
    $currentPart .= ($bracketsOpened > 0 ? ',' : '').$part;
    if (stristr($part,"(")){
        $bracketsOpened ++;
    }
    if (stristr($part,")")){
        $bracketsOpened --;                 
    }
    if (!$bracketsOpened){
        $parts[] = $currentPart;
        $currentPart = '';
    }
}
```

Gives me the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some text
    [1] =>  Some other text with ((95,3%) MSC)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clumsy, but it does the job...

```
<?php

function split_by_commas($string) {
  preg_match_all("/\(.+?\)/", $string, $result); 
  $problem_children = $result[0];
  $i = 0;
  $temp = array();
  foreach ($problem_children as $submatch) { 
    $marker = '__'.$i++.'__';
    $temp[$marker] = $submatch;
    $string   = str_replace($submatch, $marker, $string);  
  }
  $result = explode(",", $string);
  foreach ($result as $key => $item) {
    $item = trim($item);
    $result[$key] = isset($temp[$item])?$temp[$item]:$item;
  }
  return $result;
}


$test = "one, two, three, (four, five, six), seven, (eight, nine), ten";

print_r(split_by_commas($test));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel that its worth noting, that you should always avoid regular expressions when you possibly can. To that end, you should know that for PHP 5.3+ you could use [str_getcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). However, if you're working with files (or file streams), such as CSV files, then the function [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) might be what you need, and its been available since PHP4.

Lastly, I'm surprised nobody used [preg_split()][3], or did it not work as needed?

[3]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php "preg_split()

Comment: Yes ken, I want to use preg_split(), but what would be the RegEx that ignores commas in brackets ?

Comment: Ah yes, good point, after trying for a min or 2 I can see that its challenging with the conditions set forth.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I also tried your solution and doesn't work. Thank you still.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it could be very difficult to parse nested brackets like
     `one, two, (three, (four, five))`
only with RegExp.