# split by comma inside braces except another braces inside braces

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-split

I want to split by comma inside braces except another braces inside braces

```
$q1 ="CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER,code DECIMAL (4,2),PRIMARY KEY (id))";
$q2 ="CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER,code TEXT)";

$r = preg_split('/\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|[()]|,/', $q1);//$q1 splitted but $q2 no
print_r($r);
```

The final result should be:

**for $q1 :**

```
   array(
         0 => id INTEGER
         1 => code DECIMAL (4,2)
         2 => PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );
```

**for $q2 :**

```
   array(
        0 => id INTEGER
        1 => code TEXT
   );
```

Comment: No one will be able to answer your question. It's too vague.

Comment: I want to split sql inside braces ... that's all!

Comment: Your question is not clear... AFAIK, you need to split this string by comma, but the `code DECIMAL (4,2)` stay intact?

Comment: Yes, I want to stay intact...

Comment: This question may be related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233953/php-split-string-on-comma-but-not-when-between-braces-or-quotes

Comment: This solution does not help

Comment: It' not a job for regex but for a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:  ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d25e7dc17cbf6ed36f3cef4ace94d73424535984))

```
$sqls = array(
    "CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER,code DECIMAL (4,2),PRIMARY KEY (id))",
    "CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER,code TEXT)"
);

foreach($sqls as $sql){
    if(preg_match_all("/(?:^.+?\(|,)(?:\K[\w ]+(?:\([\S].*?\))?)/", $sql,$matches)){
        echo "<pre>";
            var_export($matches[0]);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// first $matches...
array(
    0 => 'id INTEGER',
    1 => 'code DECIMAL (4,2)',
    2 => 'PRIMARY KEY (id)'
)
// second $matches...
array(
    0 => 'id INTEGER',
    1 => 'code TEXT'
)
```

Regex Breakdown:  ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/05Fwa1/1))

```
(?:^.+?\(|,)          #group everything from the start to 1st parenthesis or a comma
(?:\K[\w ]+           #\K means "only retain text from this point", group words and spaces
    (?:\([\S].*?\))?  #optionally group parenthetical text
)
```

Using `\K` permits the exclusion of a capture group and `preg_match_all` returns the desired string (full string) in the first subarray.  The benefit is a `$matches` array that half the size of an array with a capture group.

Comment: @edd If my answer satisfies, please award it the green tick.  Otherwise please leave me a comment that explains what remains to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If embeded parenthesis contain only digits, this does the job:

```
$sqls = array(
"CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER,code DECIMAL (4,2),PRIMARY KEY (id))",
"CREATE TABLE notes(id INTEGER,code TEXT)"
);

foreach ($sqls as $sql) {
    $arr = preg_split("/(?<!\d)[(),](?!\d)/", $sql);
    print_r($arr);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => CREATE TABLE notes
    [1] => id INTEGER
    [2] => code DECIMAL (4,2)
    [3] => PRIMARY KEY 
    [4] => id
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => CREATE TABLE notes
    [1] => id INTEGER
    [2] => code TEXT
    [3] => 
)
```

Comment: You are closer with this ideea

Comment: It is a partial answer, but I try to adapt this idea (if you have a better idea ... I wait)